# remove php extension on url

Tags: nginx, php

I have tried many ways to remove my php extension but unable to do so, here is what I'm trying to achieve.

https://google.com/users/login.php > https://google.com/users/login

Sounds easy but I can't seems to remove it, either I received 500 internal error or 404 error

```
        location  /users/ {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                rewrite ^/users/(.*) /users/(.*).php$1 break;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
#               try_files $uri =404;
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

A static solution would be:

```
location /users/login {
    try_files $uri $uri.php =404;
}
```

If you want it more dynamic you have to put it into your / location, so it would always try to deliver the request from the filesystem, if the resource of the url on the filesystem does not exist, it tries to solve the url with .php as suffix:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.php =404;
}
```